# Regular expressions returns too much - greediness?

Tags: regex, excel, vba

I can't figure out my problem.
I've got a range of strings like

```
ST078K
C022ZK
C1084A
H963F
K123AA
```

In Summary, 1 or 2 characters at the beginning, followed by 3 or 4 numbers, followed by 1 or 2 characters. However, my regex also matches without the last 1 or 2 characters present, like `AB1234`
My regex is

```
^\w{1,2}?\d{3,4}\w{1,2}$
```

with the ignore-case and global options set. Why does it not appear to care about the \w{1,2} before the end of the string?
Thanks for your help!

Comment: because \w matches digit as well

Comment: Aaargh, how stupid. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
^[A-Z]{1,2}?\d{3,4}[A-Z]{1,2}$
```

A digit is considered to be covered by \w, so the last one two word characters were matching your digits.  Replacing with [A-Z] fixes that.  Good luck!

You can find a demo of it [here](https://regex101.com/r/hL5sU2/2).